# Partition a matrix into list of sub matrices row-wise in R

Tags: r, matrix, split, partition

I have a matrix where each row is either all 1's or any number between 0 and 1. I need to partition this into list of matrices such that

1. Each sub matrix is either all 1's or all numbers between 0 and 1
2. Combining all the sub matrices of the list using *rbind* yields the original matrix

Example:

[image: Sample Matrix]

[image: List of sub matrices]

```
m <- 
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 0.84, 0.27, 0.24, 0.48, 0.28, 0.62, 0.55, 
1, 1, 0.26, 0.93, 0.87, 0.76, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.31, 0.32, 0.96, 
0.25, 0.96, 0.43, 0.66, 1, 1, 0.22, 0.88, 0.01, 0.14, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0.71, 0.99, 0.6, 0.22, 0.73, 0.54, 0.17, 1, 1, 0.59, 0.67, 
0.07, 0.4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.27, 0.62, 0.52, 0.67, 0.69, 0.06, 
0.63, 1, 1, 0.27, 0.95, 0.16, 0.22, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.59, 0.94, 
0.4, 0.05, 0.05, 0.26, 0.31, 1, 1, 0.53, 0.52, 0.77, 0.06, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.48, 0.47, 0.88, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 0.72, 1, 1, 0.79, 
0.58, 0.74, 0.4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.27, 0.41, 0.36, 0.35, 0.48, 
0.2, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.17, 0.34, 0.97, 0.06, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.56, 
0.66, 0.29, 0.41, 0.56, 0.83, 0.97, 1, 1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.47, 0.23, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.91, 0.15, 0.17, 0.82, 0.7, 0.15, 0.97, 1, 1, 
0.47, 0.02, 0.07, 0.05, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.57, 0.17, 0.92, 
0.92, 0.8, 0.73, 1, 1, 0.87, 0.5, 0.65, 0.67, 1, 1), .Dim = c(18L, 
10L))

L <- 
list(structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 10L
)), structure(c(0.84, 0.27, 0.24, 0.48, 0.28, 0.62, 0.55, 0.31, 
0.32, 0.96, 0.25, 0.96, 0.43, 0.66, 0.71, 0.99, 0.6, 0.22, 0.73, 
0.54, 0.17, 0.27, 0.62, 0.52, 0.67, 0.69, 0.06, 0.63, 0.59, 0.94, 
0.4, 0.05, 0.05, 0.26, 0.31, 0.48, 0.47, 0.88, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.72, 0.27, 0.41, 0.36, 0.35, 0.48, 0.2, 0.4, 0.56, 0.66, 0.29, 
0.41, 0.56, 0.83, 0.97, 0.91, 0.15, 0.17, 0.82, 0.7, 0.15, 0.97, 
0.9, 0.57, 0.17, 0.92, 0.92, 0.8, 0.73), .Dim = c(7L, 10L)), 
    structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 10L)), structure(c(0.26, 0.93, 
    0.87, 0.76, 0.22, 0.88, 0.01, 0.14, 0.59, 0.67, 0.07, 0.4, 
    0.27, 0.95, 0.16, 0.22, 0.53, 0.52, 0.77, 0.06, 0.79, 0.58, 
    0.74, 0.4, 0.17, 0.34, 0.97, 0.06, 0.4, 0.35, 0.47, 0.23, 
    0.47, 0.02, 0.07, 0.05, 0.87, 0.5, 0.65, 0.67), .Dim = c(4L, 
    10L)), structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 10L)))
```

Comment: Please don't post images of data. MAke your example reproducible. And, does it have to be a matrix?

Comment: If `m` is your input matrix and `L` is your output list then paste the output of running `dput(m)` and of `dput(L)` in R into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for you. It uses data.table's rleid for convenience.

First, we generate some data:

```
set.seed(123)
input <- matrix(runif(180),ncol=10)
input[c(1:3,5,9:10),]<-1
```

Then we identify which rows have only ones

```
is_one <- apply(input,1,function(x){all(x==1)})
```

We want to split our rows by groups of is one/is not one, so we generate row id's and split id's

```
row_ids <- 1:nrow(input)
split_ids <- data.table::rleid(is_one)
```

The we generate our output, by splitting the row id's by groups of is one/is not one and returning our input data for each set of row ids.

```
output <- lapply(split(row_ids,split_ids),function(x){input[x,]})
```

Comment: `split.data.frame(input, split_ids)`

Comment: @Srikrishna ; if this answers your question, you can click the tick mark to mark it as so if you wish (you can also give a wee upvote if you are so inclined by clicking the up arrow - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split.data.frame` with a matrix:

```
> m=structure(c(1,1,1,0.84,0.27,0.24,0.48,0.28,0.62,0.55,1,1,0.26,0.93,0.87,0.76,1,1,1,1,1,0.31,0.32,0.96,0.25,0.96,0.43,0.66,1,1,0.22,0.88,0.01,0.14,1,1,1,1,1,0.71,0.99,0.6,0.22,0.73,0.54,0.17,1,1,0.59,0.67,0.07,0.4,1,1,1,1,1,0.27,0.62,0.52,0.67,0.69,0.06,0.63,1,1,0.27,0.95,0.16,0.22,1,1,1,1,1,0.59,0.94,0.4,0.05,0.05,0.26,0.31,1,1,0.53,0.52,0.77,0.06,1,1,1,1,1,0.48,0.47,0.88,0.7,0.4,0.4,0.72,1,1,0.79,0.58,0.74,0.4,1,1,1,1,1,0.27,0.41,0.36,0.35,0.48,0.2,0.4,1,1,0.17,0.34,0.97,0.06,1,1,1,1,1,0.56,0.66,0.29,0.41,0.56,0.83,0.97,1,1,0.4,0.35,0.47,0.23,1,1,1,1,1,0.91,0.15,0.17,0.82,0.7,0.15,0.97,1,1,0.47,0.02,0.07,0.05,1,1,1,1,1,0.9,0.57,0.17,0.92,0.92,0.8,0.73,1,1,0.87,0.5,0.65,0.67,1,1),.Dim=c(18L,10L))
> r=rle(rowSums(m==1)==ncol(m))$lengths
> split.data.frame(m,rep(1:length(r),r))
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1

$`2`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 0.84 0.31 0.71 0.27 0.59 0.48 0.27 0.56 0.91  0.90
[2,] 0.27 0.32 0.99 0.62 0.94 0.47 0.41 0.66 0.15  0.57
[3,] 0.24 0.96 0.60 0.52 0.40 0.88 0.36 0.29 0.17  0.17
[4,] 0.48 0.25 0.22 0.67 0.05 0.70 0.35 0.41 0.82  0.92
[5,] 0.28 0.96 0.73 0.69 0.05 0.40 0.48 0.56 0.70  0.92
[6,] 0.62 0.43 0.54 0.06 0.26 0.40 0.20 0.83 0.15  0.80
[7,] 0.55 0.66 0.17 0.63 0.31 0.72 0.40 0.97 0.97  0.73

$`3`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1

$`4`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 0.26 0.22 0.59 0.27 0.53 0.79 0.17 0.40 0.47  0.87
[2,] 0.93 0.88 0.67 0.95 0.52 0.58 0.34 0.35 0.02  0.50
[3,] 0.87 0.01 0.07 0.16 0.77 0.74 0.97 0.47 0.07  0.65
[4,] 0.76 0.14 0.40 0.22 0.06 0.40 0.06 0.23 0.05  0.67

$`5`
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```